# Change default indentation when pasting CSS from Google Inspect Element

Tags: css

When copying and pasting a CSS code from Google Chrome's Inspect Element tool, it always comes unindented.

How to make it come with 4 spaces by default, for example? Couldn't find it in the options so far.

[image: Google Inspect Element Copy]
[image: Google Inspect Element Paste]

Answer (score 0):

i habe a similiar problem. when i copy CSS it is indented with 4 spaces but i dont like this because i work with classic tabulators.

in Linux (Fedora) i have managed that Chrome doesnt copy "Soft Tabs" and does not make any Indents.classics Tabs havent worked here so no Indents are better than Soft Tabs because with Soft Tabs i have to re-indent the code everytime i copy my on-the-fly changes from the Debugger Tools. and i do this offen.

Under Windows 7 or 8 i havent found any setting in the developer settings that had any effect in the copied CSS Indents...